# unable to show text on the image

Tags: php, gd

I want to show some text on an image. I am using the following code :

```
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$nameLength = strlen($name); // gets the length of the name
$randomNumber = rand(0, $nameLength - 1); // generates a random number no longer than the name length
$string = ucfirst(substr($name, $randomNumber, 1)); // gets the substring of one letter based on that random number
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("love.jpg");
$text = "  First Letter of Your partner's name is";
$font = "Font.ttf";
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$black1 = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagettftext($im, 32, 0, 380, 430, $black, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 52, 0, 630, 530, $black1, $font, $string);
imagejpeg($im, null, 90);
```

but on `localhost` this code is showing the text on the image but when I am uploading it to server then it is showing only `image`, text is not shown on this image ? what may be the problem?

`$_SESSION['name'] is value when I login to facebook and save the name of the user into $_SESSION`

I have uploaded the above code on the server :

`http://rohitashvsinghal.com/fb/login.php`

Comment: check GD and Image Functions is enabled or not?

Comment: Chances are that the path to the fonts is not suitable - try using realpath() with the absolute path to the font location

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal how to check for this function ?

Comment: @JasbirSinghSohanpal if GD is disabled then I think image should also be not seen

Comment: check it using phpinfo(); function.

Comment: I have uploaded phpinfo() at the url http://rohitashvsinghal.com/fb/login.php it is saying GD is enabled

Comment: @RamRaider I have used realpath but when I am trying to echo value of realpath('font.ttf') then it is returning blank

Comment: that means the path is incorrect - realpath returns false if the path is wrong..

Comment: but at localhost it is returning the path and It contains the font.ttf in the same folder

Comment: when I am removing font.ttf `$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("love.jpg");
$text = "  First Letter of Your partner's name is";
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$black1 = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
imagettftext($im, 32, 0, 380, 430, $black, $text);
imagettftext($im, 52, 0, 630, 530, $black1, $string);` then also I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font must exist in the location specified obviously and the fullpath to the font works best in my experience.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $nameLength = strlen($name);
    $randomNumber = rand(0, $nameLength - 1);
    $string = ucfirst(substr($name, $randomNumber, 1));
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("love.jpg");
    $text = "  First Letter of Your partner's name is";

    /* Either use the fullpath or the method given below from the manual */
    $fontpath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/fonts/';
    putenv('GDFONTPATH='.realpath( $fontpath ) );

    $fontname='arial.ttf';
    $font = realpath( $fontpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fontname );


    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $black1 = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
    imagettftext($im, 32, 0, 380, 430, $black, $font, $text);
    imagettftext($im, 52, 0, 630, 530, $black1, $font, $string);
    imagejpeg($im, null, 90);
?>
```

However, the manual states:-

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.
>
> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script
>   using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'SomeFont';
?>
```

Comment: One more thing I want to ask that if I want to post this image on facebook then How can I post ?

Comment: I guess that depends upon how the code above is used. If this is a single script, named something like "love.php" and you use it in your php/html like `<img src='love.php' alt='ooh baby love' />` etc then what I would try would be to add an entry in your .htaccess file on your server that renames it to love.jpg etc and then post the full link to that file, such as `http://rohitashvsinghal.com/love.jpg`